# Can I copy the CollapsiblePanelExtender in jQuery as one method?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, collapsiblepanelextender, onclientclick

I am beginning the process of moving away from the AjaxControlToolkit and toward jQuery.  What I want to do is have one function that duplicates the functionality of the CollapsiblePanelExtender.  For a particular set of hyperlink and div, the code looks like this:

```
$('#nameHyperLink').click(function() {

        var div = $('#nameDiv');
        var link = $('#nameHyperLink');
        if (div.css('display') == 'none') {
            link.text('Hide Data');
            div.show(400);
        }
        else {
            link.text('Show Data');
            div.hide(400);
        }

    });
```

What I really want to do is only have to write this function once, then use it for many (approx 40) instances throughout my website.  Ideally what I want is this:

```
function showHidePanel(divID,linkID,showText,hideText){
        var div = $(divID);
        var link = $(linkID);
        if (div.css('display') == 'none') {
            link.text('Hide Data');
            div.show(400);
        }
        else {
            link.text('Show Data');
            div.hide(400);
        }

    });
```

I would then call this function from every HyperLink involved using OnClientClick.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the jquery [accordian](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) plugin?